# Code::Blocks command prompt font size

Tags: c++, windows, command-prompt

I'm trying to make a text RPG in C++ using Code:Blocks. Currently the font size for the command window is really small and I'm trying to make it bigger. I've tried to change it in the command prompt properties but it doesn't seem to change it in Code:Blocks; only in normal command prompt. 
Does anyone know how to change the default font size for the command window in Code:Blocks???

Comment: Did you make the change "for all command windows" rather than "just this one"? It should work. I'm 99% sure that Code:Blocks do not alter the default size.

Comment: In command prompt menu there is "Properties" and "Default", you have to change "Default" settings as well. I don't this is Code::Blocks specific.

Comment: yay it works!!! thank you!